# Create a safe nullpointer in regards to memory leaks

Tags: c, arrays, null-pointer

Look at this:

```
    char (*options)[MAXLEN];
    char *ptr;
    ptr = strtok(input, " \r\n");
    if(!ptr)
        continue;
    int i = 0;
    optionen = malloc(sizeof(*options));
    if(!options)
        die("malloc");
    while(ptr){
        if(i > 0){
            options = realloc(options, (i+1)*sizeof(*options));
            if(!options)
                die("malloc");
        }
        strcpy(options[i], ptr);
        if(!options[i])
            die("strcpy");
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " \r\n");
        i++;
    }


/*create another entry options[i] that is a nullpointer*/
```

Purpose is that the exec(3) command requires a nullpointer as the last entry to the *options[] array to work properly.

Problem: How can I add another entry to the array that is a NULL - pointer? I understand that I cannot allocate another `options[i]` and set it to `NULL` because some guy on stackoverflow told me to never do that (memory leak).

Note: input is some array that contains some commandline - input(`char input[MAXLEN];` ) and `die()` just calls `perror()` and then `exit()`

Comment: Don't believe what they said. Allocate another entry and set its value to `NULL`.

Comment: can you give me an example line how to do it?

Comment: Do I read & parse correctly that in `char (*options)[MAXLEN];`, `options` is a pointer to an array of `MAXLEN` characters? Is that the intention?

Comment: yes that is the intention

Comment: Josch, then why do you do `strcpy(options[i], ptr);
` if you know that `options[i]` is a single char? Did you turn compiler warnings on?

Comment: compiled with all warnings (-pedantic -Wall -Werror .... ) and it worked just fine. I printed the array afterward and it showed the desired behaviour.

Comment: I guess your advice was to allocate enough memory for the array to contain a final sentinel element which you set to `NULL` (as opposed to allocating memory for the last element to point to and then overwriting its value with `NULL` which would cause the memory leak you mention). Note that passing a `NULL` pointer to `free` is benign.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever told you that you "cannot allocate another `options[i]` and set it to NULL" was wrong.  That is exactly what you do.

However, you have bugs in your code, and the bugs suggest that you don't understand what it *means* to "allocate another `options[i]`."

```
char (*options)[MAXLEN];  /* This is wrong */
char *ptr;
ptr = strtok(input, " \r\n");
if(!ptr)
    continue;
int i = 0;
optionen = malloc(sizeof(*options));
if(!options)
    die("malloc");
while(ptr){
    if(i > 0){
        options = realloc(options, (i+1)*sizeof(*options));
        if(!options)
            die("malloc");
    }
    strcpy(options[i], ptr); /* This is also wrong */
    if(!options[i])
        die("strcpy");
    ptr = strtok(NULL, " \r\n");
    i++;
}
```

First off, `char (*options)[MAXLEN]` is the wrong kind of array, and an entry in it *cannot* be set to NULL.  You need instead `char **options`.

Second off, `realloc` operation that you are already doing is, in fact, allocating more `options[i]` slots.  But you *also* need to allocate space for the strings themselves (but *not* for the NULL).  You do that with `strdup`.

```
options[i] = strdup(ptr); /* Instead of the "also wrong" line */
```

(Depending on what `input` is, you might be able to get away with just using the string pointers `strtok` returns, but without seeing more of your code I can't be sure that's safe.)

And then, after the loop, you simply set the final `options[i]` slot to NULL and you're done.

I would structure the loop a bit differently, like this:

```
char **options;
char *ptr;
size_t i, asize;

ptr = strtok(input, " \t\r\n");
if (!ptr) continue;

options = 0;
i = 0;
asize = 2;
do {
    while (i >= asize) {
        asize *= 2;
        options = xreallocarray(options, asize, sizeof(char *));
    }
    options[i++] = xstrdup(ptr);
    ptr = strtok(0, " \t\r\n");
} while (ptr);

while (i >= asize) {
    asize *= 2;
    options = xreallocarray(options, asize, sizeof(char *));
}
options[i] = 0;

execve(options[0], options, environ);
die("execve");
```

The functions `xreallocarray` and `xstrdup` are nonstandard, but they should be in your bag of simple functions that you add to every program that you write.  Here are their definitions.  They use the die() function you already have.

```
void *
xreallocarray(void *optr, size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    /* s1*s2 <= SIZE_MAX if both s1 < K and s2 < K where K = sqrt(SIZE_MAX+1) */
    const size_t MUL_NO_OVERFLOW = ((size_t)1) << (sizeof(size_t) * 4);

    if ((nmemb >= MUL_NO_OVERFLOW || size >= MUL_NO_OVERFLOW) &&
        nmemb > 0 && SIZE_MAX / nmemb < size) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        die("malloc");
    }

    void *rv = realloc(optr, size * nmemb);
    if (!rv)
        die("malloc");
    return rv;
}

char *
xstrdup(const char *s)
{
    size_t n = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *rv = malloc(n);
    if (!rv)
        die("malloc");
    memcpy(rv, s, n);
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: Zwol, I strongly suggest you use the standard functions such as `realloc` and not push your preferred own functions. Your functions are not documented and do not explain what they do or why what they do is necessary, nor for which platform they are written.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: Create another array as follows and use it in the call to `exec`.

```
char** args = malloc((i+1)*sizeof(*args));
for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j )
{
   args[j] = options[j];
}
args[i] = NULL;

execvp(..., args);
```